# Дата в Golang и MongoDB

Tags: golang, mongodb

Например у меня есть дата в виде строки `2018-02-06T00:46:24-05:00`, как мне её записать в MongoDB чтоб он понял что это именно дата а не строка и как потом сделать выборку по типу выбрать все документы у которых дата в определенном диапазоне, который прийдет из реквеста?

Answer (score 1):

Структура:

```
    type Comment struct {
        Id string `json:"id"`
        Text string `json:"text"`
        Date time.Time `json:"date"`
    }
    type CommentsCollection []Comment
```

Пример создания коллекции:

```
date, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, dateString)
collection = append(collection, Comment{id, content, date})
```

В базу пишу циклом:

```
for _, comment := range parse() {
        result, _ := session.DB("parser").C("comments").Find(bson.M{"id": comment.Id}).Count()
        if result == 0 {
            session.DB("parser").C("comments").Insert(comment)
        }
    }
```

Функция parse() возвращает CommentsCollection

Поиск:
Структура:

```
type DateInterval struct {
    Start time.Time `json:"start"`
    End time.Time `json:"end"`
}
```

Ну и пример получения отфильтрованных документов

```
    var results CommentsCollection
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(request.Body, 1048576))
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    if err := request.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var dateInterval DateInterval

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dateInterval); err != nil {
        if err := json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(err); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")

    if err!= nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.Close()

    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    err2 := session.DB("parser").C("comments").Find(bson.M{"date": bson.M{"$gte": dateInterval.Start, "$lte": dateInterval.End}}).All(&results)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "json")
    io.WriteString(response, string(jsonResponse))
```